# Is there a way to specify global resolutions in Yarn 1?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, lerna

I'm using Node 10 for some automated pipelines and now when calling `yarn global add lerna`, it's pulling in a transitive dependency, `@npmcli/fs@1.1.0` which was released a few days ago and [introduces a breaking change that requires Node 12+](https://github.com/npm/fs/issues/8). I suspect somewhere a package is using a caret for this instead of an exact version in its dependencies list.

Is there some way to tell Yarn to use `@npmcli/fs@1.0.0` instead? Resolutions don't seem to work for global packages.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a package.json in a folder and set your resolution in it. then use the lerna from your `node_modules` folder to execute any command.

for example:
`./node_modules/.bin/lerna bootstrap`